filling years series based on id in Python
I have a dataset with country and years. The years are from 2023-2003 in descending order. However, for some countries the years are missing completely from 2023-2003. There are some countries that appears one two are three times. I want to fill years column for only those countries for which the years is completly missing i.e., from 2023-2003, not for those that appeared for only one, two or three years. For instance in this sample dataset i want to fill years for China and Pakistan not for the France and Bangladesh.
    import pandas as pd
    data = {'country': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'China', 'China', 'China', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'France', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Pakistan', 'Bangladesh'],
    'year': [2023, 2022, 2021, '', '', '', 2023, 2022, 2021, '', '', '', '', ''],
    'value1': [10, 15, 20, 30, 35, 40, 50, 60, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 11],
    'value2': [55, 15, 21, 22, 33, 45, 50, 60, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 9]
}

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df

The output should look like this


can you provide an example of what you want the output to look like?

In your question you said your data is between 2023-2003, but the examples given are 2021-2023, which is correct?

Yes, the original dataset is between 2023-2003, but the sample data in example is between 2023-2003.

You can use a combination of groupby.cumcount and groupby.transform:
m = df['year'].eq('') # if NaNs use m = df['year'].isna()
g = m.groupby(df['country'])

df.loc[g.transform('sum').eq(3),
       'year'] = g.cumcount().rsub(2023)

Variant from an arbitrary list of values:
missing = [2023, 2022, 2021]

m = df['year'].eq('')
g = m.groupby(df['country'], sort=False)

df.loc[g.transform('sum').eq(len(missing)),
       'year'] = g.cumcount().map(dict(enumerate(missing)))

Output:
       country  year  value1  value2
0          USA  2023      10      55
1          USA  2022      15      15
2          USA  2021      20      21
3        China  2023      30      22
4        China  2022      35      33
5        China  2021      40      45
6        India  2023      50      50
7        India  2022      60      60
8        India  2021       9       9
9       France            10      10
10    Pakistan  2023      11      11
11    Pakistan  2022      12      12
12    Pakistan  2021      13      13
13  Bangladesh            11       9

Intermediates:
       country  year  value1  value2      m  group  cumcount  rsub(2023)  transform('sum')  eq(3)
0          USA  2023      10      55  False      0         0        2023                 0  False
1          USA  2022      15      15  False      0         1        2022                 0  False
2          USA  2021      20      21  False      0         2        2021                 0  False
3        China            30      22   True      1         0        2023                 3   True
4        China            35      33   True      1         1        2022                 3   True
5        China            40      45   True      1         2        2021                 3   True
6        India  2023      50      50  False      2         0        2023                 0  False
7        India  2022      60      60  False      2         1        2022                 0  False
8        India  2021       9       9  False      2         2        2021                 0  False
9       France            10      10   True      3         0        2023                 1  False
10    Pakistan            11      11   True      4         0        2023                 3   True
11    Pakistan            12      12   True      4         1        2022                 3   True
12    Pakistan            13      13   True      4         2        2021                 3   True
13  Bangladesh            11       9   True      5         0        2023                 1  False

Output for the second approach using missing = ['A', 'B', 'C']:
       country  year  value1  value2
0          USA  2023      10      55
1          USA  2022      15      15
2          USA  2021      20      21
3        China     A      30      22
4        China     B      35      33
5        China     C      40      45
6        India  2023      50      50
7        India  2022      60      60
8        India  2021       9       9
9       France            10      10
10    Pakistan     A      11      11
11    Pakistan     B      12      12
12    Pakistan     C      13      13
13  Bangladesh            11       9

